# Hash Table Collisions Conceptual

Tags: java, hashtable, collision

I am trying to create a `method` that counts how many collision occur in a hash table. Would I check the entire `table` to see how many `buckets` have more than 1 `element`? 
 
Draft:

```
 public int getCollisions() {
 int counter = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
     if (buckets.length > 1) {
         counter += i;
     }
 }
 return counter;
 }
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I would do. Actually, you would increment a counter with every bucket length greater then 1. So, `if (bucket.length > 1) { counter += bucket.length; }`

Comment: Would it be alright for me to propose a draft method for you to check @Elliott Frisch?

Comment: The draft method is not adding the number of collisions, rather the index of the bucket.

Comment: Would it be buckets.length then, similar to Elliot's post?

Comment: See my answer (specifically the bit after the code), but basically yes, and you also had a faulty if statement condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use this -

```
public long getCollisions() {
  long counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
    if (buckets[i].length > 1) {
      counter += buckets[i].length; // 2 (or more) items collided in this bucket.
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am not able to do `buckets[i].length`, shouldn't length be a default method?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the index of the bucket, not the number of collisions to your counter.  Try this instead:

```
public int getCollisions() {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
        if (buckets[i].length > 1) {
            counter += buckets[i].length-1;
        }
    }
    return counter;
 }
```

Here I am assuming that if there are n objects in a bucket (where n>1), there are n-1 collisions in that bucket.  If I am incorrect in assuming that, then just remove the -1 and it should work fine.